# What does it mean by (±20%) in sensitivity of a pressure sensor?

Tags: error-analysis, sensor, piezoelectric

Sensitivity: (±20%) 15.5 pC/psi (225 pC/bar)

this the sensitivity rating of a pressure sensor.
what does it mean by (±20%).